# What is the good way to collect data from screen?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

For example i have a screen with multiple textfields (name, surname, address, phone etc) and after button click need to collect that data and pass to registration module. What is the good way to collect that data?

Comment: do you only need to collect the data and pass to another viewcontroller or you want to store that data too ?

Comment: you can pass the data using segue and view controllers transition and if you want to store use database services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple options here like

1. `SQLite`: Its pretty old way of saving and fetching data as it has lots of things to do while using.
2. `Core Data`: This is the most used way if you have multiple fields like first name, last name, email, mobile, gender, state, city, etc
3. `Singleton Class` with required fields: If you want to use properties on multiple places and with less number of initialisation, then go for with approach.
4. `NSUserDefaults`: Basically this should be used if you are saving some flags and small properties like user ID or user name.
5. `plist (Property List)`: It is a flexible and convenient format for storing application data.

So as per my knowledge you can prefer Core Data as you good amount of fields and core data is easy way. And you can use same core data model for multiple entities when you want to add some more tables and fields in it.

Answer (score 0):

1). Best way is to use FMDB if you want to store registration detail from textfield.

[Download FMDB from Github](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/master/src/fmdb)

2). If you want to store and get only few registration data at a time then you can use NSUserDefaults for store data temporary and as well as retrieved.